# Objective Lower Bound command? Using PULP with COIN_CMD/CBC/CLP

Tags: linear-programming, pulp, coin-or-cbc, coin-or-clp

I'm using PULP to solve an LP with CBC with a fracgap(epgap) of 0.01 (99.99%).  Is there a command to return the best lower bound found after the solver finishes?  So, whatever the solver is comparing the objective value to in order to know its within 0.01 and it can stop.

Comment: How?  I have the final solution and the gap %, but the final solution i get could be anywhere between the lower bound and the %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but Pulp does not return the best bound of the solution, with COIN_CMD(). 
I think it is printed to stdout if msg=1 is used if you just what to see what it is.

Comment: Thanks Stu, will work with it.  Great product thanks for everything.

Comment: With the `PULP_CBC_CMD` solver it is actually possible to retrieve the lower bound of the MIP, using a trick (examining the logs file). I've developped that answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75031855/13706904.